# Is correct to say "You press it on to a pad of ink" or should "onto" be always the right choice?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

[image][image]I just came across this two sentences: You press it onto an pad of ink./You press it on to an ink pad.

Collins Cobuild. COBUILD Advanced Learner’s Dictionary KINDLE-ONLY EDITION (Posición en Kindle173077). HarperCollins Publishers. Edición de Kindle.

The thing is, if the separate use of "on and "to" changes the meaning of the sentence in contrast as when you use the preposition "onto". I think it just means the same. I am very

Comment: "Onto" is the correct preposition. To separate them here would be incorrect. More importantly, "an pad" is a horrible mistake, it should be "a pad".

Comment: See the previous response to the question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181888/onto-versus-on-to

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's wild; the original print has a typo.

Probably the best way to say this would be either "you press it onto a pad of ink" or "you press it onto a*n* ink pad"